# Is it possible to save the text entered into an alert's textfield in SwiftUI and display it in the app like this -> Text("alert text input here")?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, alert, textfield

So far I was able to handle displaying a textfield in an alert in which a user can input some text, but have not been able to use that text and display it inside the app.

Here's the code for the alert:

```
private func alert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Name", message: "...or pseudo", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter something"
    }
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default) { _ in })
    let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
    alertInput = textField.text ?? "Name"
    showAlert(alert: alert)
}
    
func showAlert(alert: UIAlertController) {
    if let controller = topMostViewController() {
        controller.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to implement it in the body:

```
Section {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
                self.alert()
            }
        }) {
            Text(alertInput)
        }
    }
}
```

`alertInput` is initialized before the body like so:

```
@State private var alertInput = ""
```

Comment: The Answer works properly, full code including "topMostViewController()" found here https://velog.io/@wimes/SwiftUI-Alert-TextField

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to grab the value of the text field from inside the Done button's handler. So all you need to do is move the bracket down:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default) { _ in
    let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
    alertInput = textField.text ?? "Name"
})
```

The code inside this closure is called when the user taps this UIAlertAction you have set up.

Note that if the field is left empty, the value of `textField.text` will be `""` and not `nil`, so in order to use the default value you provide, you may need some additional logic here to check for a blank string as well.